# change tr color when dropdown list is changed by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th style="width: 15%;">Name</th>
       <th style="width: 15%;">Marks</th>
       <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>

    <tr id="tableId">
        <td  style="text-align:centre;">any value</td>
        <td  style="text-align:left;">other value</td>
        <td  style="text-align:left;">
            <select id="comboId"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now i want to change the  colors only when the drop down list is changed. Can any one help me for this by jQuery

Comment: Ok,show us your efforts,we will correct.

Comment: Show us your **jQuery** -- What did you try?

Comment: I am trying it, but all where i get the same for checkboxes only. i also once did for combo box , but in that case only the first tr is getting updated

Comment: Please include the jQuery code you've tried - the whole point of StackOverflow is for people to help and guide you to being a better developer, not to write the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gTsHf/13/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".comboId" ).change(function() {

    //make your chnages here
  $(this).closest('tr').css('color','red');
});
});
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th style="width: 15%;">Name</th>
       <th style="width: 15%;">Marks</th>
       <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>

    <tr id="tableId">
        <td  style="text-align:centre;">any value</td>
        <td  style="text-align:left;">other value</td>
        <td  style="text-align:left;">
            <select class="comboId">
                 <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                 </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tableId">
        <td  style="text-align:centre;">any value</td>
        <td  style="text-align:left;">other value</td>
        <td  style="text-align:left;">
            <select class="comboId">
                 <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                 </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tableId">
        <td  style="text-align:centre;">any value</td>
        <td  style="text-align:left;">other value</td>
        <td  style="text-align:left;">
            <select class="comboId">
                 <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                 </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tableId">
        <td  style="text-align:centre;">any value</td>
        <td  style="text-align:left;">other value</td>
        <td  style="text-align:left;">
            <select class="comboId">
                 <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                 </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: but this code is working for first row only, not for subsequent tr and in my case the number of tr is variable

Comment: @user2190050 check Update answer and fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gTsHf/13/ i have done using class ..give class name to dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You looking for something like this?

```
$('#comboId').change(function(){
    $('#tableId).css('background-color', '#ccc');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#comboId").on("change", function() {
        $(this).parent().css("background-color", "red"); 
    });
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nevster/XFuB7/).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( "#comboId" ).change(function() {
  $( "#tableId" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onchange` function.

http://jsfiddle.net/w7EKT/

Answer (score 0):

Give a class to all the Dropdowns to which you want to add this functionality.

And apply this event to the class - comboDropdown (for example)

```
$("select.comboDropdown" ).change(function() {
$(this).parent().parent().css( "background-color", "YOUR COLOR" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#comboId" ).change(function() {

    $(this).closest('tr').css('background','red');
});
});
```

and add options to select

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th style="width: 15%;">Name</th>
       <th style="width: 15%;">Marks</th>
       <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>

    <tr id="tableId">
        <td  style="text-align:centre;">any value</td>
        <td  style="text-align:left;">other value</td>
        <td  style="text-align:left;">
            <select id="comboId">
                 <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                 </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the **[[Demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/gTsHf/12/)**